# bash script not running properly

Tags: bash

When I run this by its self in the command line it seems to work fine, but when I have another script execute this, it doesn't work. Any ideas?  I'm guessing it has to do with quotes, but not sure.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Required csvquote from https://github.com/dbro/csvquote
#TODO:  Clean CSV File using CSVFix
#Version 3
echo "File Name: $1"
function quit {
    echo "Quitting Script"
    exit 1
}
function fileExists {
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]
        then
            echo "File $1 does not exists"
            quit
        fi
}
function getInfo {
    #Returns website url like:   "http://www.website.com/info"
    #Reads last line of a csv file, and gets the 2nd item.
    RETURN=$(tail -n 1 $1 | csvquote | cut -d ',' -f 2 | csvquote -u)
    echo $RETURN 
}
function work {
    CURLURL="http://127.0.0.1:9200/cj/_query"
    URL=$(getInfo)
    echo "URL: $URL"
    CURLDATA='{ "query" : { "match" : { "PROGRAMURL" : '$URL' } } }'
    #URL shows up as blank...???
    echo "Curl Data: $CURLDATA"
    RESPONSE=$(curl -XDELETE "$CURLURL"  -d "$CURLDATA" -vn)
    echo $RESPONSE
    echo "Sleeping Allowing Time To Delete"
    sleep 5s
} 

fileExists $1
work $1
```

Comment: expand on "doesn't work". have you tried tracing it with bash -x

Comment: Why are you putting single quotes around `$URL`? (variables don't expand in single quotes in [tag:bash]). Also if you are intending to use [tag:bash] I would generally use a bash shebang, #!/bin/sh is [tag:dash] on a number of systems (won't necessarily cause errors, but could for some bash specific cases).

Comment: @BroSlow Take a close look, $URL is actually outside the quotes - try it for yourself in a shell ...

Comment: Note: on the likely assumption you are not 'sourcing' this script, there is no point setting `IFS` in `quit`.

Comment: You seem to be going a little over the top with variables etc. - there is no need to have getInfo save its results in a variable then echoing it, that is redundant

Comment: @AndrewMcDonnell Woops, I can't count. Still would switch it to explicitly `bash` and follow `pinoyyid's` suggestion.

Comment: Why are you finishing the body of `work` with `< $1`

Answer (score 1):

I cant see why a simpler version wont work: functions are useful, but I think there are too many, overcomplicating things, if what you are posting is the entirety of your script (in my opinion)

Your script is doing things using a broken lucky pattern: `$1` variables are also arguments to shell functions as well as the main script. Think of them as local variables to a function.  So when you are calling `$(getInfo)` it is calling that function with no argument, so actually runs `tail -n 1` which falls back to stdin, which you are specifying to `work` as `< $1`.  You could see this for yourself by putting `echo getInfo_arg_1="$1" >&2` inside the function...

Note also you are not quoting `$1` anywhere, this script is not whitespace in file safe, although this is only more likely to be a problem if you are having to deal with files sent to you from a Windows computer.

In the absence of other information, the following 'should' work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && { echo "Please specify a file." ; exit 1; }
test -f "$1" || { echo "Cant see file '$1'." ; exit 1; }

FILE="$1"

function getInfo() {
    #Returns website url like:   "http://www.website.com/info"
    #Reads last line of a csv file, and gets the 2nd item.
    tail -n 1 "$1" | csvquote | cut -d ',' -f 2 | csvquote -u
}


CURLURL="http://127.0.0.1:9200/cj/_query"
URL=$(getInfo "$FILE")
echo "URL: $URL"
CURLDATA='{ "query" : { "match" : { "PROGRAMURL" : '$URL' } } }'
curl -XDELETE "$CURLURL"  -d "$CURLDATA" -vn
echo "Sleeping Allowing Time To Delete"
sleep 5s
```

If it still fails you really need to post your error messages.

One other thing, especially if you are calling this from another script, `chmod +x` the script so you can run it without having to invoke it with `bash` directly. If you want to turn on debugging then put `set -x` near the start somewhere.

Comment: There are no "error" messages really, It's not setting the $URL variable.  So the curl request is: { "query" : { "match" : { "PROGRAMURL" :  } } }

Comment: As far as I an tell it's not running tail.  I edited the script above to just output tail -n 1 "$1" and no output.